# Найти в тексте русские слова, которые начинаются на гласную букву

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Какое регулярное выражение может подойти для решения этой задачи?

Задача: Найти в тексте русские слова, которые начинаются на гласную букву

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Сделайте регулярное выражение нечуствительным к регистру (не хочу дублировать строчные и заглавные буквы): `\b[аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-]*`, либо через lookbehind `(?<=^|\s)[аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-]*`. Регулярное выражение простое: начинаем на гласные, а в далее ищем любое количество букв и дефис.

Если допустимы цифры внутри слова (к примеру чтобы находило `Ан-10`, `А4`), то регулярное выражение будет `\b[аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-0-9]*`, либо через lookbehind `(?<=^|\s)[аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-]*`.

К сожалению, данный пример не будет работать на JavaScript, так как у него проблемы с обработкой с помощью регулярных выражений:

1. Не поддерживает `\b` для не-ASCII текста.
2. Не поддерживает lookbehind.

Поэтому надо делать что-то вроде

```js
// Берём строки начало текста или пробелы,
// потом первую гласную букву
// затем русский буквы, дефис, цифры
// Сохраняем само слово в группу
var regex = /(?:^|\s)([аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-0-9]*)/gi

// Пример текста
var str = "Аня Кристина алина коля яна. ЯНА радость ЁЖИК проверка";

// Здесь будет храниться результат
var words = [];

// Удаляем начальные пробелы, оставляя сами слова
var match = regex.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  words.push(match[1]);
  match = regex.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: Во второй части выражения вы забыли `ё`, которое не входит в диапазон `[а-я]`

Comment: @VenZell Хорошо, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: **Update**: добавил дефис для не-Unicode регулярного выражения.

Comment: Зачем перечислять все буквы алфавита? Если регулярные выражения не поддерживают юникод, то внутри символьного класса юникод распадется на отдельные байты например `[а]` распадется на `[\x04\x30]` и будет успешно совпадать и с `\x04` и с `\x30`. Если уж заводить речь о отсутствии поддержки юникода, то правильным регулярным выражением будет: `(а|б|в|г|...)`

Comment: @ReinRaus я не понял ваших мыслей, если тут что-то фундаментально не так, то можете предложить свой ответ.

Comment: Не вижу смысла писать ответ. Завтра покажу на примере. Если не трудно, и Вам интересно о чём я говорю- соберите пример на JS, который продемонстрировал бы НЕ поддержку юникода. Я просто сильно ограничен во времени чаще всего.

Comment: Это не значит, что он не поддерживает юникод... Это лишь означает, что специфика `\b` в его реализации регулярных выражений не поддерживает языки, отличные от английского. Вы скорее всего путаете Unicode Ranges с самой кодировкой. JavaScript- один из немногих языков в котором обработка текста изначально происходит как юникод. Впрочем, Ваше исправление в ответ убирает проблему и теперь в нём нет неправильной трактовки.

Comment: Начиная с es6 в js реализованы диапазоны юникода, кстати. Будет красиво, если Вы это уточните в самом ответе.

Comment: @ReinRaus Спасибо за внимание к моему ответу, благодаря нему я внёс исправления. И по поводу поддержки unicode я тоже знаю, просто неверно выразился. JavaScript поддерживает Unicode в самой строке, но не поддерживает обработку Unicode в регулярных выражениях. То есть `\d` это цифры 0-9, а не все цифры Unicode. `\w` это буквы и цифры `0-9a-zA-Z`, а не все буквы юникод и т. д.

Comment: @ReinRaus EcmaScript 6 безусловно добавил удобства, но я не вижу как он сильно облегчит создание регулярного выражения, к примеру, для данного случая.
Кстати, справедливости ради отмечу, что в вопросе _нигде_ не упоминалось, что нужен JavaScript.

Comment: Вы писали про JS и не поддержку Unicode. Потому я и оставил комментарий к ответу. Юникодовые символы- это несколько байт, если некий движок не поддерживает кодировку юникод, то он воспримет эти несколько байт как несколько отдельных символов. Например «а» на кириллице станет двумя отдельными символами с кодами 4 и 30 в 16-ной системе счисления. Теперь рассмотрим сокращенное регулярное выражение из предыдущей версии Вашего ответа: `[абв]` без поддержки юникода станет `[\x04\x30\x04\x31\x04\x32]`.

Comment: В es6 \b нормально работает, так что регулярное выражение будет простым.

Comment: @ReinRaus а можно пример с \b в es6?

Comment: Нет, не могу. Несмотря на эти обещания https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex еще ни один браузер не поддерживает нормально флаг u в регулярных выражениях. По той же ссылке сведения о багах, которые связаны с этим флагом. Когда-нибудь ситуация изменится и `/\b[аеёиоуыэюя][а-яё\-]*/ug` будет искать как положено.

Comment: @ReinRaus ну вот тогда и дополним ответ.

Comment: Согласен :) Информация с этой страницы была очень похожа на правду, поэтому воспринял ее как уже реализованное.

Comment: На данный момент в JavaScript границу слова с поддержкой Unicode можно реализовать с помощью [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) (используя группы/подмаски с использованием исключающих символьных классов).